# Python array data to integer

Tags: python, arrays, string

I have an array with 4 integer elements for example [1,0,1,0]
I want to convert it into string '1010'
How do that?

I've tried this

```
 b=''.join(str(syndrome_noised.T))
    print(b)
```

but I got '[1,0,1,0]'.

How this string without brackets.

Comment: `''.join(map(str, items))`

Comment: Or `''.join(str(x) for x in items)`.

Answer (score 1):

The reason this fails is because you apply `str(..)` to the matrix. This will generate a **single string**. This string is however *iterable*, so you `''.join(..)` the characters of that string back together, turning it into the original string again.

What you probably need to do, is convert every *single* element into a string, and then join these together, like:

```
b = ''.join(str(x) for x in syndrome_noised.T)
```

We thus iterate over the elements `x` in the `syndrome_noised.T` array, and we each time map it to a `str(..)`, we then join these together.

We can shorten the code a bit, but still have the same semantics, with `map`:

```
b = ''.join(map(str, syndrome_noised.T))
```

Answer (score 1):

```
syndrome_noised = [1,0,1,0]
''.join(str(x) for x in syndrome_noised)
```

Answer (score 0):

you could do this by using a for loop like below:

```
text = str()
for i in array:
   text += str(i)
print(text)
```

and that would return 1010

Comment: This will result in an *O(n^2)* algorithm, since in order to concatenate the string, we each time make a copy.